# MemberNotNullWhen along with a parameter name

Tags: c#, .net

If `heartbeat` is `true`, the nullability warning over `heartbeatTarget` should go away. I remember there was the MemberNotNullWhen attribute. How do I use it in this case in order to disable the nullability warning over `heartbeatTarget`?

However, it won't compile due to `typeof(heartbeat)` it should be something else but not sure what.

```cs
internal static IGraph<SourceShape<IFeedMessage>,NotUsed> CreateGraph<TMat>(
    Source<string,TMat> publisher,
    bool                heartbeat       = false,
    [property: MemberNotNullWhen(true, typeof(heartbeat))]
    IActorRef?          heartbeatTarget = null,
    ILoggingAdapter?    log             = null
)
{
    var graph = GraphDsl.Create(builder =>
    {
        var origSource = builder.Add(publisher);
        var filter = builder.Add(Flow.Create<string, string>().WhereNot(x => string.IsNullOrEmpty(x)));
        var serializer = builder.Add(GdaxFeedFlows.JsonDeserializeFlow(log));
        builder.From(origSource.Outlet).To(filter.Inlet);
        builder.From(filter.Outlet).To(serializer.Inlet);
        var emptyFilter = builder.Add(GdaxFeedFlows.FilterEmpty());

        // add heartbeat detection capabilities if requested
        if (heartbeat)
        {
            var heartbeatFilter = builder.Add(GdaxFeedFlows.FilterHeartbeats(heartbeatTarget));
            builder.From(serializer.Outlet).To(heartbeatFilter.Inlet);
            builder.From(heartbeatFilter.Outlet).To(emptyFilter.Inlet);
        }
        else
        {
            builder.From(serializer.Outlet).To(emptyFilter.Inlet);
        }

        return new SourceShape<IFeedMessage>(emptyFilter.Outlet);
    });

    return graph;
}
```

Comment: It won't compile _chiefly_ because you cannot use `[property: ]` attributes to target _parameters_. Parameters are not members (the `[property: ]` syntax is for use with `record` types, not methods) Secondarily, there is no `MemberNotNullWhen` ctor that accepts a `Type` parameter - may I ask where you got that idea from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MemberNotNullWhen` doesn't work like that. You are only allowed to attribute Methods and Properties with it which is why you put a `[property:]` as a compiler workaround.

Null annotations is supposed to help with compile time null-ref exceptions, but I don't think any of the current annotations would help here. Even if `heartbeat` is `true`, the `heartBeatTarget` could still be null since it's the callers responsibility to pass it in. You can't just assume it'll be true because you'll get a null ref.

I think you would be better off checking if it's not null at runtime.

Null check

```cs
        // add heartbeat detection capabilities if requested
        if (heartbeat && heartBeatTarget is not null)
        {
            var heartbeatFilter = builder.Add(GdaxFeedFlows.FilterHeartbeats(heartbeatTarget));
            builder.From(serializer.Outlet).To(heartbeatFilter.Inlet);
            builder.From(heartbeatFilter.Outlet).To(emptyFilter.Inlet);
        }
```